# DynamoDB Event Scheduling Table Structure

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm building out a scheduling app, where users can invite other users to events. However, I'm having a little trouble figuring out how I want to set up my tables.

Since DynamoDB is a NoSQL database we want to try to keep data that is related, in the same table. However, this problem gets a bit more confusing because some events for my app may have roles, such as organizer, planner, etc. Therefore, I want users for an event to be able to accept the invitation to the event with specific roles.

Therefore, in this case, would I want to use two tables, one that stores the event (UUID, Name, etc.) and the other that has the users attending events (UUID of Event, Username, etc.) or use one table?

Plus, when I create my get request to fetch the event data if I use two tables, would I have to query the user table to get the number of people attending that event or should I store that value in the event table, and then when a user signs up, add a new row to the users table, and update the number of people attending in the event table?

For the app I am using Lambda functions on AWS.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have

- userid as **hash-key**
- eventid as **range-key**
- role as **LSI**

You can also have a **GSI** on event-id to query based on eventid

sample table:

1. user1, event1, organizer
2. user2, event1, planner
3. user3, event1, attendee
4. user4, event1, attendee

Comment: For the event, would I have another table that contains, the date, time, and location for that event, or would that information just be copied between users?

Comment: @JackIrish You could have another table which has info about all users and events in overloaded manner.  
So, the hash_key would be **id** and value could be either eventid or userid and rest can be attributtes.  
e.g.  `
1. user1, Jack, xyz-city, date-of-birth,...  
2. event1, <address>, <time>  `
and so on...